# How to use the info after index.php?something

Tags: php

I've read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php), but it's all about `index.php?name=something`. I want to use the info after `?` to use it to `echo "$_GET";`, but i have to define the `$_get['name'];`. The point is, I want to use it without `?name=`. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: so, all you want is `something`?

Comment: I want to use multiple things. Otherwise i would've used if($_GET == something), but I want to use a lot of words, so it's impossible to make all if( etc..

Comment: You can't `echo $_GET` as `$_GET` is an associative array. You could `print_r($_GET)` or `var_dump($_GET)`

Comment: I think you should do some reading about PHP and arrays

Comment: @JvdBerg, yes, and also maybe about `GET`, `POST` and `HTTP Request` in general

Comment: Hey read my new answer, I think I got what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get it from `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`.

And you still could get it form `$_GET`, try `array_keys($_GET)`

Comment: +1 This is my best guess as well.

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
function getstuffbehindurl() {
  $urlstring = "";
  foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
    $urlstring .= "$key" . ($value == "") ? "" : "=$value&";
  }
  $urlstring = substr($urlstring, 0, -1);
  return $urlstring;
}
```

If your url was `foo.php?something&somethingelse&somethingelse`, this would give you `something&somethingelse&somethingelse`.

Then you could use:

```
include(getstuffbehindurl());
```

Comment: But this is only for ?something, right? The point is, I have dozens of possible words. It's impossible to use ifs for all the possible words.

Comment: Whats the point of this? $values = array_values($_GET);

Comment: `foreach ($_GET as $key)` should be `foreach ($_GET as $key => $value)`, you need the key not value.

Comment: @ArtZeeman So, maybe you could explain in further detail. What are you trying to detect?

Comment: if the page is index.php?ery804067507 i want to include "ery804067507.php";

Comment: @ArtZeeman What do you mean 'include'?

Comment: I think you should not `answer` a question if the guy who is asking has no clue whatsoever what he is asking!

Comment: with include, i mean php include

Comment: @ArtZeeman Oh, so like `include ('stuffinurl');`? That is extremely insecure.

Comment: I know, think123. I have some security things for it. Thanks for your answer, it works now.